# Are a bonsai tree and its normal version the same species?

Tags: species, trees

I would like to know if bonsai type of a tree is a separate species from its normal version. Do they differ by genes, or is it just a matter of different physical care?

Can I grow a bonsai tree from seed of a normal outdoor tree (of course, I understand that not every species will endure being dwarfed)? Can I grow a normal outdoor tree from some seeds labeled "bonsai"?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should go to Gardening.SE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. For any species that it is possible to grow as a bonsai tree, it is also possible to grow that species as a non-bonsai tree. The process of creating a bonsai tree involves growing a tree in a severely restricted pot with a minimal amount of soil, and trimming both the roots and branches to maintain a desired shape and size. It is the small growing space and regular pruning which keeps bonsai trees small, [not the genetics of the tree](http://www.bonsaiforbeginners.com/selecting-bonsai-stock.html).

You may wish to check the [list of species used in bonsai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_species_used_in_bonsai) on Wikipedia to get a sense of which species make good bonsai plants.

Comment: What if we grew bonsai trees for many generations, selecting the individuals "most suited" for the bonsai process? I don't know how long it would take, but eventually there should be genetic changes to help the plants adapt to the selection.

Comment: Sure, you could. That would be standard artificial selection. But given that bonsai as currently practiced doesn't require such selective breeding, why would you make the effort?